# Shrink my code, Please

Tags: c

I wrote this stupid chunk of code as an answer for a program exercise from the book "c programming a modern approach 2nd E." by K.N.King, namely ch7;ex4.

I couldn't make it does the same thing with less code, so, Can you?

It's just converting alphabetic phone numbers into numeric form, i'm really curious to see a better coding of this..

Thanks..

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{   
    char c;
    int phone_number;

    printf("Enter phone number: ");

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if(c == 'A' || c == 'B' || c == 'C')
            printf("2");
        if(c == 'D' || c == 'E' || c == 'F')
            printf("3");
        if(c == 'G' || c == 'H' || c == 'I')
            printf("4");
        if(c == 'J' || c == 'K' || c == 'L')
            printf("5");
        if(c == 'M' || c == 'N' || c == 'O')
            printf("6");
        if(c == 'P' || c == 'R' || c == 'S')
            printf("7");
        if(c == 'T' || c == 'U' || c == 'V')
            printf("8");
        if(c == 'W' || c == 'X' || c == 'Y')
            printf("9");
        if(c == '0')
            printf("0");
        if(c == '1')
            printf("1");
        if(c == '2')
            printf("2");
        if(c == '3')
            printf("3");
        if(c == '4')
            printf("4");
        if(c == '5')
            printf("5");
        if(c == '6')
            printf("6");
        if(c == '7')
            printf("7");
        if(c == '8')
            printf("8");
        if(c == '9')
            printf("9");
        if(c == '-')
            printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Consider the fact that `char`s in C can be thought of simply as integers between `0` and `255`. Does that help?

Comment: `0-9` could be handled by `printf("%d",c - '0')`, right?

Comment: In C99, you can use designated initializers to make a lookup table.

Comment: Any of the others could be handled by `if (c <= 'C')`, `if (c <= 'F')`, etc.

Comment: well @nhgrif printf("%d",c-'0')

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hmmmm, interesting, i'll try that...

Comment: Thanks @GradyPlayer, wasn't sure... to many languages.

Comment: until you get to Q : c = (letter - 'A') / 3 +2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that characters are sequential (not sure if this is standard, but it happens in most representations, anyway)

Let's make a table specifying which number a letter represents. It would look something like

```
int keynum[26] = {2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9};
```

`keynum[0]` is the number that `A` maps to, and so on. If we have a character `c` and we need to get the proper index in `keynum` we calculate it by `c-'A'`

Then our main loop would be:

```
while((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
    if (c>='0' && c<='9')
         putchar(c);
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
         putchar('0' + keynum[c-'A'])
    /* else error? */
}
```

Comment: characters aren't always sequential... not according to the standard, but in practice every encoding I have ever had to use had sequential a-z and A-Z and 0-9

Comment: You made a typo. It should be `keynum[c-'A']`, with square brackets, not parentheses.

Comment: this isn't a bad approach, it could be simpler, keynum[] could just be 128 bytes and contain all the valid 0-127 ascii things with corresponding keynum... including `*` and `#` can't be simpler or faster than that.

Comment: @user3079683 I mixed ints and chars, sorry! My edit should fix it!. Could have been better to make a char array like `{'2', '2', etc..}`

Answer (score 0):

`2 + ((c-'A') / 3)` (integral division) is the number you print for A-Y (*if* `'A'<=c && c<='O'`!)

Comment: x and q screw that up

Comment: @GradyPlayer While that's true, the code in the OP implied that all groups are of 3 letters. My solution was for an actual phone keyboard, but this one is perfect for the OP if this is what he needs.

Comment: the absence breaks your code too, because ascii still contains them... basically you will get the wrong answer for t,and w

Comment: True, sorry about that!